# One column for each record/ row of a query's result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a database with parts that are stored in a table "Part". Each part undergoes a certain measurement (to determine its diameter) that is stored in the table "Measurement". The measurement uses a certain set of rules that are stored in a table "Ruleset". The rules are used to asses the part's category (it is possible that it matches multiple categories). So there is a cross table "Ruleset_x_Category" that's primary key is the combination of the foreign keys "ID_Ruleset" and "Category" to ensure that this combination is unique (each rule set can be combined with each category only ones) that is further connected the rule itself which than holds a Diameter_min- and Diameter_max-Value to check if the part matches the category. The number of rules per rule set varies.

[image]

The workflow: you have a part, you measure it, you pick a rule set for the measurement and then you are supposed to get a list that tells you if the part fit's in a number of categories.

Most of this is straight forward. Query for rules, get a "yes/no" if measurement is in between the min/max and so on. What is not easy to me is to get a new column for each row that I get if I query for the (variable number of) rules. Is this possible? And if so what is the technique that I use. Is there a better way to arrange my tables?

```
 SELECT  Measurement.id_part, Measurement.diameter, Category.Name, IIF(Measurement.diameter BETWEEN [Rule].Diameter_min AND [Rule].Diameter_max, 'Yes', 'No') As HitsCategory
 FROM Measurement INNER JOIN
                      RuleSet ON Measurement.id_ruleset = RuleSet.ID INNER JOIN
                      RuleSet_x_Category ON RuleSet.ID = RuleSet_x_Category.Id_RuleSet INNER JOIN
                      [Rule] ON RuleSet_x_Category.id_rule = [Rule].Id INNER JOIN
                      Category ON RuleSet_x_Category.id_category = Category.Id
```

This get's me this:

[image]

What I want to have is this:

[image]

Larnu gave me the tip to use the pivot keyword. I found [this article](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/), however, I have trouble to apply it to my IIF statement. What I have tried:

```
 DECLARE 
     @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
     @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

 -- select the category names
 SELECT 
     @columns+=QUOTENAME([Name]) + ','
 FROM 
     Category
 ORDER BY 
     [Name];

 -- remove the last comma
 SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

 -- construct dynamic SQL
 SET @sql ='
 SELECT * FROM   
 (
 SELECT Measurement.id, Measurement.id_part, Measurement.diameter, RuleSet.ID, Category.Name
 FROM Measurement INNER JOIN
                      RuleSet ON Measurement.id_ruleset = RuleSet.ID INNER JOIN
                      RuleSet_x_Category ON RuleSet.ID = RuleSet_x_Category.Id_RuleSet INNER JOIN
                      [Rule] ON RuleSet_x_Category.id_rule = [Rule].Id INNER JOIN
                      Category ON RuleSet_x_Category.id_category = Category.Id
 ) t 
 PIVOT(
    IIF(Measurement.diameter BETWEEN [Rule].Diameter_min AND [Rule].Diameter_max, ''true'', ''false'')
     FOR [Name] IN ('+ @columns +')
 ) AS pivot_table;';

 -- execute the dynamic SQL
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

This gave me the Error:

```
 Msg 195, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
 'IIF' is not a recognized aggregate function.
```

Here is a script to create a demo data base I use to tinker with this problem:

```
 USE [master]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Database [Demo]    Script Date: 6/10/2020 2:14:59 PM ******/
 CREATE DATABASE [Demo]
  CONTAINMENT = NONE
  ON  PRIMARY 
 ( NAME = N'Demo', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Demo.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
  LOG ON 
 ( NAME = N'Demo_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Demo.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140
 GO
 IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
 begin
 EXEC [Demo].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
 end
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET ARITHABORT OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET RECOVERY FULL 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET  MULTI_USER 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 60 SECONDS 
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
 GO
 EXEC sys.sp_db_vardecimal_storage_format N'DemoPivot', N'ON'
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET QUERY_STORE = OFF
 GO
 USE [DemoPivot]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Category]    Script Date: 6/10/2020 2:14:59 PM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](70) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Category] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [Id] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Measurement]    Script Date: 6/10/2020 2:14:59 PM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Measurement](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Id_Part] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id_RuleSet] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Diameter] [float] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Measurement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [Id] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Part]    Script Date: 6/10/2020 2:14:59 PM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Part](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](70) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Part] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [Id] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Rule]    Script Date: 6/10/2020 2:14:59 PM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rule](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Diameter_min] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Diameter_max] [float] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Rule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [Id] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RuleSet]    Script Date: 6/10/2020 2:14:59 PM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RuleSet](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_RuleSet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [Id] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category]    Script Date: 6/10/2020 2:14:59 PM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category](
    [Id_RuleSet] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id_Category] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id_Rule] [int] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_RuleSet_x_Category] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [Id_RuleSet] ASC,
    [Id_Category] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Category] ON 
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'A')
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'B')
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (3, N'C')
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (4, N'D')
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (5, N'E')
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (6, N'F')
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (7, N'G')
 GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Category] OFF
 GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Measurement] ON 
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Measurement] ([Id], [Id_Part], [Id_RuleSet], [Diameter]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 12)
 GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Measurement] OFF
 GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Part] ON 
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Part] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'myPart')
 GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Part] OFF
 GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Rule] ON 
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Rule] ([Id], [Diameter_min], [Diameter_max]) VALUES (1, 10, 12)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Rule] ([Id], [Diameter_min], [Diameter_max]) VALUES (2, 11, 13)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Rule] ([Id], [Diameter_min], [Diameter_max]) VALUES (3, 12, 15)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Rule] ([Id], [Diameter_min], [Diameter_max]) VALUES (4, 13, 18)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Rule] ([Id], [Diameter_min], [Diameter_max]) VALUES (5, 13, 19)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Rule] ([Id], [Diameter_min], [Diameter_max]) VALUES (6, 14, 16)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[Rule] ([Id], [Diameter_min], [Diameter_max]) VALUES (7, 15, 17)
 GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Rule] OFF
 GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[RuleSet] ON 
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[RuleSet] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'myRule')
 GO
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[RuleSet] OFF
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category] ([Id_RuleSet], [Id_Category], [Id_Rule]) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category] ([Id_RuleSet], [Id_Category], [Id_Rule]) VALUES (1, 2, 2)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category] ([Id_RuleSet], [Id_Category], [Id_Rule]) VALUES (1, 3, 3)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category] ([Id_RuleSet], [Id_Category], [Id_Rule]) VALUES (1, 4, 4)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category] ([Id_RuleSet], [Id_Category], [Id_Rule]) VALUES (1, 5, 5)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category] ([Id_RuleSet], [Id_Category], [Id_Rule]) VALUES (1, 6, 6)
 GO
 INSERT [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category] ([Id_RuleSet], [Id_Category], [Id_Rule]) VALUES (1, 7, 7)
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Measurement]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Measurement_Part] FOREIGN KEY([Id_Part])
 REFERENCES [dbo].[Part] ([Id])
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Measurement] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Measurement_Part]
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Measurement]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Measurement_RuleSet] FOREIGN KEY([Id_RuleSet])
 REFERENCES [dbo].[RuleSet] ([Id])
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Measurement] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Measurement_RuleSet]
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RuleSet_x_Category_Category] FOREIGN KEY([Id_Category])
 REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([Id])
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RuleSet_x_Category_Category]
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RuleSet_x_Category_Rule] FOREIGN KEY([Id_Rule])
 REFERENCES [dbo].[Rule] ([Id])
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RuleSet_x_Category_Rule]
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RuleSet_x_Category_RuleSet] FOREIGN KEY([Id_RuleSet])
 REFERENCES [dbo].[RuleSet] ([Id])
 GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RuleSet_x_Category] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RuleSet_x_Category_RuleSet]
 GO
 USE [master]
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [Demo]SET  READ_WRITE 
 GO
```

(background: I want to use this as a stored procedure from entity framework core in c# that is then the item source of a wpf (mvvm) data grid with a variable number of columns).

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about a Pivot. What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? **Consumable** sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: Yes, sure. Takes a moment since I have to re-simplefy my SQL (the reality is -of course- much more complex with employees, machines, batches, departments ....)

Comment: Usually, this kind of thing is best done in your client code or reporting tool. The SQL language has a **very strict requirement** that you know the number and types of columns at query compile time, _before_ looking at any data. You can use the PIVOT keyword to dynamically name the columns, but you still have to define them up front. If you want to rotate data rows to become columns, you must use a three step process: 1) Run a query to tell you about your desired columns, 2) Use those results to build a new query dynamically, and then, 3) Run the query from step 2.

Comment: Now, it sounds like you're doing that. The trick is `IIF()` is an MS Access function. It's not part of the ansi SQL standard. Sql Server requires you to use a `CASE` expression, which is standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the values "yes"/"no" or "true"/"false" to be displayed because I could not work around the aggregate function that the PIVOT statement demands.

So I used a CASE statement that outputs 1 or 0, as Joel Coehoorn recommended.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE 
        @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
        @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    -- select the category names
    SELECT 
        @columns+=QUOTENAME([Name]) + ','
    FROM 
        Category
    ORDER BY 
        [Name];

    -- remove the last comma
    SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

    -- construct dynamic SQL
    SET @sql ='
    SELECT * FROM   
    (
     SELECT  Measurement.id_part, Category.Name,
     Case 
        When Measurement.Diameter BETWEEN [RULE].Diameter_min AND [Rule].Diameter_max
            THEN 1
        Else
            0
            End As Hit
     FROM Measurement INNER JOIN
                          RuleSet ON Measurement.id_ruleset = RuleSet.ID INNER JOIN
                          RuleSet_x_Category ON RuleSet.ID = RuleSet_x_Category.Id_RuleSet INNER JOIN
                          [Rule] ON RuleSet_x_Category.id_rule = [Rule].Id INNER JOIN
                          Category ON RuleSet_x_Category.id_category = Category.Id
    ) t 
    PIVOT(
        sum(hit)
        FOR [name] IN ('+ @columns +')
    ) AS pivot_table;';

    -- execute the dynamic SQL
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

And this is my result:

[image]

I have now three parts, each with a mesurement. If the diameter fits the rules criteria I get a 1, if not a zero. I can work with that.

I have now created a stored procedure that I can (hopefully) run from my app.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCategories @idmesurement int 
 AS
    DECLARE 
        @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
        @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    -- select the category names
    SELECT 
        @columns+=QUOTENAME([Name]) + ','
    FROM 
        Category
    ORDER BY 
        [Name];

    -- remove the last comma
    SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

    -- construct dynamic SQL
    SET @sql ='
    SELECT * FROM   
    (
     SELECT  Measurement.id_part, Category.Name,
     Case 
        When Measurement.Diameter BETWEEN [RULE].Diameter_min AND [Rule].Diameter_max
            THEN 1
        Else
            0
            End As Hit
     FROM Measurement INNER JOIN
                          RuleSet ON Measurement.id_ruleset = RuleSet.ID INNER JOIN
                          RuleSet_x_Category ON RuleSet.ID = RuleSet_x_Category.Id_RuleSet INNER JOIN
                          [Rule] ON RuleSet_x_Category.id_rule = [Rule].Id INNER JOIN
                          Category ON RuleSet_x_Category.id_category = Category.Id
    WHERE Measurement.id = '+ CONVERT(varchar(10),@idmesurement) +'
    ) t 
    PIVOT(
        sum(hit)
        FOR [name] IN ('+ @columns +')
    ) AS pivot_table;';

    -- execute the dynamic SQL
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

With

```
GetCategories @idmesurement = 1
```

only outputs the result for my Measurement with the id=1.

Thanks a lot!